# JMeter use of Random Order Controller

Tags: jmeter

I am using the Stepping Thread Group so that I constantly increase threads (users in system) every minute. I then have a Random Order Controller, containing several Simple Controllers, which in turn contain HTTP Requests:

```
Stepping Thread Group (Test Suite)
    Random Order Controller (used to execute test cases randomly)
        Simple Controller1 (Test Case)
            HTTP Requests (Test Steps)
        Simple Controller2 (Test Case)
            HTTP Requests (Test Steps)
        Simple Controller3 (Test Case)
            HTTP Requests (Test Steps)
```

My idea is that the thread group will execute the simple controllers (Test Cases) in random order, and do so constantly until defined time runs out. So my questions are:

1) If I have an almost infine amount of users in CSV file, will this setup basically continue running the test cases in ranodm order continuously, or will each thread execute only once and then it just stops

2) If JMeter has ramped up all e.g. 150 threads, does that mean that 150 threads have been executed, or that 150 threads are now running concurrently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly find the clarifications below:

My idea is that the thread group will execute the simple controllers (Test Cases) in random order, and do so constantly until defined time runs out.

1) If I have an almost infine amount of users in CSV file, will this setup basically continue running the test cases in ranodm order continuously, or will each thread execute only once and then it just stops

**It is not time based, it depends on the no. of threads e.g. if you set no. of threads to "5" and loop count to "1", all 5 threads/users will randomly go to only 1 simple controller. the test execution will stop after all 5 threads have finished the intended task, unless you have set the loop count to "forever", it will never stop.**

2) If JMeter has ramped up all e.g. 150 threads, does that mean that 150 threads have been executed, or that 150 threads are now running concurrently?

**you have to check in the top-right corner of Jmeter, if you see 150/150 test is still in execution. if it is 0/150, that means test has stopped.**

Hope this will help.